# PHP & Bootstrap - Modal Shown just before content updated

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

In the database I have a table called *articles*. On one page of my website there is a list of titles of all articles - and each title is actually a link to edit the article. It looks like this:

```
<a onclick="launch_edit_modal(<?php echo $article->getId(); ?>)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_modal" href="#">Edit</a>
```

When you click on the link - function *launch_edit_modal(id_of_article)* is triggered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#edit_modal').modal({
       show: false
   });

   function launch_edit_modal(id) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "return_article_data.php",
        data: {
            id:id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#category").val(data.category_id);
            $("#title").val(data.title);
            $("#content").val(data.content);
            $('#edit_modal').show();
        }
     });
   }
</script>
```

This script is at the bottom.

So, using AJAX I find the other data (category, title, content) about that article and then I update the form which is modal's content:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Edit article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <form id="edit_forma" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="edit_article.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <!-- Select Basic -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Category:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
                                        <?php foreach($categories as $c): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $c->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $c->getName(); ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Textarea -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="content">Content:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="10"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Izmeni</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">
                    Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of this works - but there is a **problem** - when I click on *edit link* - Modal is shown, and then **after 2 or 3 seconds** the form is filled (updated) with data.

Is there a way to fix this - to show Modal after the form is filled (updated)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to preventDefault(). Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289575/showing-ajax-call-result-in-bootstrap-modal

Comment: or you need to set for ajax call async: false

Comment: @Ghazanfar Mir Yes, that solved the problem. Please answer the question so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Ghazanfar Mir** wrote in the comments below my question, I need just to set:

```
async: false
```

for ajax call, and the problem is solved.

Thank you Ghazanfar Mir.